# How to list ruby production only dependencies using Gemfile.lock and LockfileParser class

Tags: ruby

I have a tool that analyze some ruby projects having Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files. This tool given in input the path where ruby project is, list all its dependencies.

My problem is that I only need to print production dependencies excluding development and test. Today I find out that my code does not exclude them and I do not know how to modify it for my purpose. **How I can remove development and test dependencies from the list?**

Here a simplified version of the ruby code I use to list dependencies:

```
project_path = ARGV.map {|path| File.expand_path(path) }

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = project_path+"/Gemfile"

lockfile_path=project_path+"/Gemfile.lock"

lockfile_contents = File.read(lockfile_path)
parser = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(lockfile_contents)

lockfile_contents = File.read(lockfile_path)
parser = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(lockfile_contents)

to_fetch = []
parser.specs.each do |spec|
    gem_basename = "#{spec.name},#{spec.version}"
    to_fetch << gem_basename
end

to_fetch.uniq!
to_fetch.sort!
```

The variable to_fetch contains the dependencies.

Here the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "cf-message-bus", git: "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-message-bus.git"
gem "vcap_common", git: "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-common.git"
gem "aws-sdk", '~> 2', require: false
gem "steno"
gem "httparty"

group :test do
    gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: false
    gem "rake"
    gem "rspec"
    gem "ci_reporter"
    gem "timecop"
    gem "webmock"
end
```

Let me know if you need also the Gemfile.lock that is 149 lines long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave my other answer in case it helps someone else: Here is the revised version based on what I think you want

```
require 'bundler'

class DependencyTree
  attr_reader :definition
  def initialize(gemfile,lockfile)
    @gemfile = gemfile
    @definition = Bundler::Definition.build(gemfile,lockfile,nil)
  end

  def all_dependencies
    return @all_dependencies if @all_dependencies
    collect_dependencies
  end

  def inspect
    "#<#{self.class.name}:#{self.object_id} Gemfile: #{Pathname.new(@gemfile).expand_path} >"
  end

  def lock_file
    @definition.locked_gems
  end

  def to_h
    lock_file.specs.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |lock,obj|
      gem_file_dep = all_dependencies.detect {|dep| dep[:name] == lock.name} || {group: :unknown}
      name = lock.full_name.dup
      name << " (#{gem_file_dep[:error]})" if gem_file_dep[:error]
      obj[gem_file_dep[:group]] << name                    
    end
  end

  private 
    def groupify(dep)
      dep.groups.map do |g| 
        a = [{group: g, name: dep.name}] 
        begin
          a << runtime_dependencies(g,dep.to_spec)
        rescue Gem::LoadError => e
          a[-1] =  {group: g, name: dep.name,error: 'NOT INSTALLED'}
        end
      end
    end
    def collect_dependencies
      @all_dependencies = @definition.dependencies.map do |dep|
          groupify(dep)
      end.flatten
      group_missing
      @all_dependencies.uniq!
    end
    def runtime_dependencies(group,spec)
      spec.dependencies.select { |dep| dep.type == :runtime}.map do |dep|
          a = {group: group, name: dep.name}
          dep.to_spec.dependencies.empty? ? a : [a] << runtime_dependencies(group,dep.to_spec)
      end
    end
    def group_missing
      all_locks.cycle(2) do |a|
        deep_dep = @all_dependencies.find_all {|h| a.include?(h[:name])}.uniq
        a.each do |k|
          deep_dep.each do |h|
            all_dependencies << {group: h[:group], name: k, error: 'NOT INSTALLED'}
          end
        end
      end
    end
    def all_locks
      lock_file.specs.map do |spec|
        spec.to_lock.delete(' ').split("\n").map do |s| 
          s.slice(/^[\w\-]+/)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

the usage is:

```
 dt = DependencyTree.new('Gemfile','Gemfile.lock') 
 dt.to_h
```

output Snippet:

```
{:default=>
  ["actionmailer-4.2.5.2 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "actionpack-4.2.5.2",
   "actionview-4.2.5.2",
   "activejob-4.2.5.2 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "activemodel-4.2.5.2",
   "activerecord-4.2.5.2",
   "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.17",
   "activesupport-4.2.5.2",
   "arel-6.0.3 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "axlsx-2.0.1 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "binding_of_caller-0.7.2 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "builder-3.2.3",
   "coffee-rails-4.1.1 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "coffee-script-2.4.1 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "coffee-script-source-1.12.2 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "concurrent-ruby-1.0.4",
   "debug_inspector-0.0.2 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "erubis-2.7.0",
   "execjs-2.7.0"],
:development=>
  ["airbrussh-1.1.2",
   "byebug-9.0.6 (NOT INSTALLED)",
   "capistrano-3.7.2"],
:doc => ["sdoc-0.4.2 (NOT INSTALLED)"]}
```

production gems will be in `:default` development gems would be `:default` + `:development`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I really appreciate it. locked_gems method is undefined for definition in 

def lock_file
    @definition.locked_gems
end

How I can address this?

Moreover, I have the impression that I need to have required .gem file installed somewhere. 
Currently I have them in <myproject>/vendor/cache.
How I can make my code find them?

Comment: Ok Solved. I just replaced it with: lockfile_contents = File.read('Gemfile.lock')
    Bundler::LockfileParser.new(lockfile_contents)

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
require 'bundler'

dependencies = Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile','Gemfile.lock',nil).
     dependencies.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |dep,obj| 
       dep.groups.each do |g|
         obj[g] << {name: dep.name,
          required_version: dep.requirement.requirements.join,
          actual_version: dep.to_spec.version.to_s
          }
       end
end
```

This will group all the dependencies by their group and place them in `Hash`es containing their name, their required version and their specific version. For example:

```
{:default=>
  [{:name=>"rake", :required_version=>"=11.3.0", :actual_version=>"11.3.0"},
   {:name=>"rails", :required_version=>"=4.2.5.2", :actual_version=>"4.2.5.2"},
   {:name=>"arel", :required_version=>"=6.0.3", :actual_version=>"6.0.3"},
   {:name=>"activerecord",
    :required_version=>"~>4.2.0",
    :actual_version=>"4.2.8"},
   {:name=>"activerecord-sqlserver-adapter",
    :required_version=>"~>4.2.0",
    :actual_version=>"4.2.18"},
   {:name=>"tiny_tds", :required_version=>"~>0.7.0", :actual_version=>"0.7.0"}],
 :doc=>
  [{:name=>"sdoc", :required_version=>"~>0.4.0", :actual_version=>"0.4.2"}],
 :development=>
  [{:name=>"byebug", :required_version=>">=0", :actual_version=>"9.0.6"},
   {:name=>"web-console",
    :required_version=>"~>2.0",
    :actual_version=>"2.3.0"},
   {:name=>"capistrano",
    :required_version=>"=3.7.2",
    :actual_version=>"3.7.2"}],
 :test=>
  [{:name=>"byebug", :required_version=>">=0", :actual_version=>"9.0.6"}]}
```

BTW `:default` is production (might need to expand further to handle dependencies of dependencies I will see what I can do)

**Update 1**: Similar formatting lists `:runtime` dependencies of dependencies (not uniq)

```
  def dep_to_hash(dep)
    {name: dep.name,
      required_version: dep.requirement.requirements.join,
      actual_version: dep.to_spec.version.to_s,
      dependencies: dep.to_spec.dependencies.select {|d| d.type == :runtime}.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |dep2,obj|
        obj[dep2.type] << dep_to_hash(dep2)
      end
      }
  end


  deps = Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile','Gemfile.lock',nil).
     dependencies.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |dep,obj| 
       dep.groups.each do |g|
         obj[g] << dep_to_hash(dep)
       end
  end
```

Output snippet:

```
 {:default=>
  [{:name=>"rails",
    :required_version=>"=4.2.5.2",
    :actual_version=>"4.2.5.2",
    :dependencies=>
     {:runtime=>
       [{:name=>"activesupport",
         :required_version=>"=4.2.5.2",
         :actual_version=>"4.2.5.2",
         :dependencies=>
          {:runtime=>
            [{:name=>"i18n",
              :required_version=>"~>0.7",
              :actual_version=>"0.8.1",
              :dependencies=>{}},
             {:name=>"json",
              :required_version=>">=1.7.7~>1.7",
              :actual_version=>"1.8.6",
              :dependencies=>{}},
```

**Update 2** (More like what you seem to be targeting now and is uniq by "group")

```
    require 'bundler'
    def add_to_dep(dep,top_level)
      deps = dep.to_spec.dependencies.select {|d| d.type == :runtime}
      deps.each do |dep|
        add_to_dep(dep,top_level) 
      end
      # handle existing dependencies by using highest version
      exists = top_level.grep(/#{dep.name}/)[0]
      if exists
        version = exists.split(',').last
        new_version = dep.to_spec.version.to_s
        if new_version > version
          top_level.delete_at(top_level.index(exists))
          top_level << "#{dep.name}, #{dep.to_spec.version}" 
        end
      else
        top_level << "#{dep.name}, #{dep.to_spec.version}"
      end  
    end


    deps = Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile','Gemfile.lock',nil).
       dependencies.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |dep,obj| 
         dep.groups.each do |g|
           add_to_dep(dep,obj[g])
         end
    end.each {|_k,v| v.sort!}
```

Output Snippet:

```
{:default=>
  ["actionmailer, 4.2.5.2",
   "actionpack, 4.2.8",
   "actionview, 4.2.8",
   "activejob, 4.2.5.2",
   "activemodel, 4.2.8",
   "activerecord, 4.2.8",
   "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, 4.2.18",
   "activesupport, 4.2.8",
   "arel, 6.0.4",
   "axlsx, 2.0.1",
   "builder, 3.2.3",
   "bundler, 1.14.6",
   "coffee-rails, 4.1.1",
   "coffee-script, 2.4.1",
   "coffee-script-source, 1.12.2",
   "concurrent-ruby, 1.0.5",
   "erubis, 2.7.0",
   "execjs, 2.7.0",
   "globalid, 0.4.0",
   "hash-deep-merge, 0.1.1",
   "htmlentities, 4.3.4",
   "i18n, 0.8.1",
   "jbuilder, 2.6.2",
   "jquery-rails, 4.2.2",
   "jquery-ui-rails, 6.0.1",
   "json, 1.8.6",
   "lazy_high_charts, 1.5.6",
   "loofah, 2.0.3",
   "mail, 2.6.5",
   "mime-types, 3.1",
   "mime-types-data, 3.2016.0521",
```

Comment: Wow, you're great. Thank you very much. I need time to test it but I am sure you test it and it will work. Amazing!!!

Comment: Can I ask you a question? I have projects already built that have Gemfile.lock. My understanding is that while Gemfile list the dependencies required (so even something like version>x.y) the Gemfile.lock contains the real dependencies used (the whole dependencies tree). Now suppose I have only source code of a project, how I can determine dependencies? Should I look at Gemfile or .gemspec? I know in this case I cannot know which dependencies will be used because it depends on when it will be build, but for dependencies that do not specify the exact version is ok for me to have the latest one.

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo determining the dependencies from pure source would be much more difficult. If you have a Gemfile or a gemspec it should be reasonable. If is truly just pure source code that "requires" certain dependencies then you would have to keep track of things like `$LOAD_PATH` and determine if the items added are `gems` and then leverage that for a dependency list. Additionally you would have to ensure that you can visit every file in the code base to make sure every single dependency has been loaded. I am sure this is possible but far more tedious than I intend to tackle.

Comment: I am trying your code: Update 2, but I got the following error: `<main>': undefined method `each_with_object' for #<Bundler::Definition:0x00000001844058> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Are you missing the dependencies part? `dependencies.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] })`? There is a trailing dot (`.`) on the first line which will cause the second line to be chained to it I just posted in this manner to keep it compact

Comment: Got the following error: usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cf-message-bus' (>= 0)

Comment: It seems code requuest have already been downloaded. Am I correct? What I can do to solve it?

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo you will have to install the bundle for it to find the dependencies (apparently it tries to load them). You could try passing `true` as the third argument to `Bundler::Definition` although this will force updating it seems (not 100% sure)

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo you could also trap this and tag it as a missing dependency which might make the most sense in this case

Comment: I cannot make this code working. Sorry. Going back to my code, my main problem is that I am unable to understand the LockfileParser structure, if there is a way to understand if a dependency is in the test/development group.

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo I will try and come up with something more suitable but there is no way to determine the dependency group strictly from the lock file

Comment: The problem I have is only on two gems on my vendor/cache. They are the following: 

gem "cf-message-bus", git: "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-message-bus.git"
gem "vcap_common", git: "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-common.git"

in my vendor/cache folder they are managed as folder and not as .gem file:

cf-message-bus-b48eeb4357bd
vcap-common-4ad156de3fcb

I do not know if this could be the issue

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo I have posted a new answer (could probably be cleaned up more) I think this is the desired result