# Upgrading from Rails 4.1 to 4.2 Issue with ffi/rb-inotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Migrating my Rails 4.1 app to Rails 4.2. Finally got it to build by pinning rb-inotify to version 0.9.1 (0.10.1 does not build, requiring Ruby >= 2.2; really any version from 0.9.1 to 0.9.10 gives the same results, but 0.9.1 was the version that was loaded with 4.1). When I run "rails c" I get:

```
/Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.6/lib/ffi/library.rb:261:in `attach_function': Function 'inotify_init' not found in [libc.dylib] (FFI::NotFoundError)
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.1/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:24:in `<module:Native>'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.1/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:9:in `<module:INotify>'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.1/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.1/lib/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.1/lib/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/jackrg/Documents/Novelty-Stats/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I was pulling in the latest version of SASS. When I changed the Gemfile to pin sass and sass-rails to older versions, this problem went away. It was difficult to find the dependency but i used DependencyTree from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681231/how-to-list-ruby-production-only-dependencies-using-gemfile-lock-and-lockfilepar) to find it.