# Figure out which gem is requesting rb-inotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Trying to figure out which gem is requesting a specific gem. Bundle won't build unless I pin the gem in question to a particular version, which hides the requesting gem info (gem looks like it was loaded from the gemfile, which it was, but only because it won't build with the latest version). How can I figure out the requesting gem?

tl;dr; I'm trying to migrate from Rails 4.1 to 4.2 on my Mac OS X system. Some gem is requesting rb-inotify, and the newest version of it won't work because it requires Ruby >= 2.2 and I'm on 2.0. I can add rb-inotify to the gemfile with version 0.9.1 in order to get the build to complete, but running my app fails in ffi in attach_function because "inotify_init" is not found in libc.dylib. rb-inotify wasn't loaded in 4.1, so my suspicion is that I'm getting a wrong version of some gem that is requesting rb-inotify when it should not be used. I'd like to see which gem has rb-inotify as a dependency, but since I had to pin it to version '0.9.1' in order to get the build, gemfile just shows it as requested by the gemfile, not any other gem. I tried to grep all my gems' gempspecs for rb-inotify but the only matches were from listen and newrelic-rpm (neither of which are included in my bundle, even after I build successfully). How can I figure out which gem is being pulled in and requesting rb-inotify?

Comment: The bundle command should tell you which gem needs a particular version. Additionally the Gemfile.lock will explain the gems and their dependencies. A while back I answered this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681231/how-to-list-ruby-production-only-dependencies-using-gemfile-lock-and-lockfilepar) mostly for fun but it might help too

Comment: The problem is that unless I put the gem in my Gemfile, it won't build a gemfile.lock (it pulls in the newest version of the rb-inotify gem which requires Ruby >= 2.2 and I have 2.0). And if I do add the gem to my gemfile (in order to request an earlier version that works with Ruby 2.0), then Gemfile.lock does not indicate who requested it, because it was requested by the Gemfile. It's a Catch-22.

Comment: The lock file will still show what gem depends on it

Comment: engineersmnky If the gem is listed in Gemfile, then Gemfile.lock does not show gems that are dependent on it. And in this case, I couldn't get it to build a gemfile.lock without adding it to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that SASS was requesting rb-inotify. It was loading the newest version of SASS, and I had to pin it (and sass-rails) to older versions. What helped me find this was the DependencyTree solution from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681231/how-to-list-ruby-production-only-dependencies-using-gemfile-lock-and-lockfilepar).

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to figure out which gem is requesting a specific gem. ... How can I figure out the requesting gem?

I wrote a bundler plugin for this, inspired by `yarn why`.

```
bundle why tzinfo
ransack -> activesupport -> tzinfo
rspec-rails -> activesupport -> tzinfo
business_time -> tzinfo
```

https://github.com/jaredbeck/bundler-why

Alternatively, you can `grep` your `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: That sounds good, unless bundler-why just reads the gemfile.lock. In the situation I was in, the bundle command failed so there was no gemfile.lock to read (or if there was one, it had not been updated with the result of the bundle). What's really needed is a tool that walks the dependency tree inside bundle while it's running.