# How to run `bundle check` and `bundle install` from inside a script without using the command line?

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I can run the following two commands from my bash shell -

```
 bundle check --gemfile=/path/to/some/Gemfile
 bundle install --gemfile=/path/to/some/Gemfile
```

How do I run these from inside a Ruby script **without** shelling out (e.g. **without** using ``, `system()`, `exec()`, etc..)?

Specifically, does Bundler offer some API like `Bundler.check()` where I can call this process and receive output on whether it was successful or not?

Thanks!

**EDIT** I'm aware that `bundler/inline` provides a way to specify a `gemfile` block within the same file, but the scope of this question is how to run `check` and `install` on any arbitrary `Gemfile`

Comment: You might want to check the source code of [the bundler CLI](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/tree/master/bundler/lib/bundler/cli) methods.

Comment: `bundler` uses `sys_exec` to check these outputs in their tests https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/4c16f55ba9544858c31df8128c558ce2864cdec8/bundler/spec/commands/check_spec.rb#L3 and https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/2b921a21acf4cd954b037d96844cd415dbda79fe/bundler/spec/support/helpers.rb#L123 so it seems that might be the easiest way to go. That being said depending on what you are interested in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681231/how-to-list-ruby-production-only-dependencies-using-gemfile-lock-and-lockfilepar) might help too

Comment: So looking through the source, I can agree with @spickerman you want to look at `Bundler#Definition`. You can use `::build` to create one from arbitrary `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` then use the instance methods like`validate_runtime!`, `missing_specs`, etc. to determine if there are any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, from within a Ruby Script

- the definition line loads the default Gemfile
- then we try to resolve all the dependencies locally, with resolve_with_cache
- if necessary, we try to resolve the dependencies remotely, which does mean installing necessary gems

```
require 'bundler'
definition = Bundler.definition
begin
  definition.resolve_with_cache!
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound => e
  puts "missing dependencies, let's try remotely"
  begin
    definition.resolve_remotely!
  rescue
    puts "damn ! could not satisfy dependencies !"
  end
end
```