# Maximum depth of dependencies tree in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile.lock

I want to parse a Gemfile.lock file as a dependencies tree.
I've noticed that the indents indicates the structure of the dependencies tree like in this example below:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    websocket-eventmachine-base (1.2.0)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0)
```

Meaning that the tree will be: **websocket-eventmachine-base -> eventmachine**

I've been trying to check what would be the maximum depth, but couldn't find any documentation about it.
So far I saw the maximum is depth of 2 (dependencies and his sub-dependencies).

Can the depth be deeper than 2?

In case it can -

A root dependency has indent of 4 spaces, his sub-dependencies will have indent of 6, can I assume the next layer will be 8?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681231/how-to-list-ruby-production-only-dependencies-using-gemfile-lock-and-lockfilepar

Comment: it is, but the below answer was directly referred to the source code so it was easier to understand :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never go beyond `gem -> dependency`, because the dependencies aren't represented as deeply nested trees. Another approach is taken: if gem A depends on B and C, B depends on D with certain constraints and C depend on D with certain constraints, the structure of `Gemfile.lock` will the the following relatively flat one:

```
...
GEM
  remote: <...>
  specs:
    A (...)
      B (...)
      C (...)
    B (...)
      D (<constraint_1>)
    C (...)
      D (<constraint_2>)
    D (version)
...
```

where `version` will be the result of dependency resolution machinery (something, that satisfies both `constraint_1` and `constraint_2`)

For the particular indentations you can always refer to the [source](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb#L175), but beware of dragons - this is not part of the public contract, so the implementation can be changed by the maintainers without any prior deprecation warnings and things like that.